# Solving a quasi-linear PDE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

Does anyone know why I just get the input back?

```
     DSolve[D[u[x, y, z], x]*x*(z - 2*y^2) + D[u[x, y, z], y]*y*
                 (z - y^2 - 2*x^3) == z*(z - y^2 - 2*x^3), 
                 u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]
```

I've obtained the two first integrals of the PDE analytically but the third is tricky so I thought I'd ask Mathematica.

$\frac{dz}{0}$ implies $z=C_1$

$\frac{y^{-1}dy+z^{-1}du}{0}=\frac{d(\log y+z^{-1}u)}{0}$ implies $\log y+\frac{u}{z}=C_2$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429541/how-to-solve-a-quasi-linear-pde

Comment: Are you sure this is a "quasi-linear" PDE? Also, what do you mean by dividing by $0$? I don't understand the maths, and their relationship with the _Mathematica_ question.

Comment: All the first derivatives appear linearly meaning it is quasi-linear. The notation is often used but it just means that $z$ is a first integral of the system. So the solution should be $F(z,e^\frac{u}{z}+y,?)=0$

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Using the definition of http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveLinearAndQuasiLinearFirstOrderPDEs.html it seems to me your PDE is simply linear. Anyway that does not answer the question.

Comment: Sure thing! Yes,  _linear_ sorry. Wondered if it wasnt one of those common pitfalls :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `z` enters into the PDE only as a parameter, it is convenient (but not necessary) to rewrite the PDE as

```
D[u[x, y], x]*x*(z - 2*y^2) + D[u[x, y], y]*y*(z - y^2 - 2*x^3) == z*(z - y^2 - 2*x^3)
```

This equation, if it can be solved, should be solved by the method of characteristics, as the OP began to do in the question.  Define in the usual way,

```
p = x (-2 y^2 + z);
q = y (-2 x^3 - y^2 + z);
r = z (-2 x^3 - y^2 + z);
```

Then, two equations determining the characteristics are

```
D[u[x, y], x] - r/p == 0;
D[u[x, y], y] - r/q == 0;
```

However, the results of solving these characteristic equations is meaningful only if the equations are consistent; i.e., if

```
Simplify[D[D[u[x, y], x] - r/p, y] == D[D[u[x, y], y] - r/q, x]]
```

is `True`.  In fact, the result is

```
(* (y (4 x^3 - z) z)/(x (2 y^2 - z)) == 0 *)
```

Hence, the characteristic equations are not, in general, consistent, just as observed by [user64494](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7152/user64494), using Maple.

The equations are, however, consistent for `z == 0`, in which case the PDE can be solved.  Setting `z -> 0` in the PDE and dividing out a common factor of `y` then gives,

```
D[u[x, y], x]*x*(z - 2*y^2) + D[u[x, y], y]*y*(z - y^2 - 2*x^3) == 
    z*(z - y^2 - 2*x^3) /. z -> 0;
Simplify[#/y & /@ %]

(* (2 x^3 + y^2) D[u[x, y], x] +2 x y D[u[x, y], y] == 0 *)
```

which can be solved by the method described in Sec 2.2 of the [article by Scott Sarra](http://www.scottsarra.org/shock/shock.html), based on solving its characteristic equation.

```
FullSimplify[DSolve[D[x[y], y] == ((p/q) /. {z -> 0, x -> x[y]}), x[y], y]]

(* {{x[y] -> (2 3^(1/3) C[1] + 2^(1/3) (9 y^2 + Sqrt[81 y^4 - 12 C[1]^3])^(2/3))/
     (6^(2/3) (9 y^2 + Sqrt[81 y^4 - 12 C[1]^3])^(1/3))}, ...}} *)
```

The second and third solutions are complex and, therefore, not useful for the real-valued PDE.  `u[x, y]` is by this method an arbitrary function of `C[1]`, expressed as a function of `x` and `y`:

```
Solve[%[[1, 1]] /. Rule -> Equal, C[1]] /. x[y] -> x

(* {{C[1] -> 0}, {C[1] -> (x^3 - y^2)/x}} *)
```

The first root corresponds to `u[x, y]` constant, which indeed does satisfy the `z == 0` PDE.  The second root corresponds to

```
u[x, y] -> c[(x^3 - y^2)/x]
```

where `c` is an arbitrary function of its argument.  To verify that this final result is correct, substitute it back into the PDE.

```
Unevaluated[(2 x^3 + y^2) D[u[x, y], y] + 2 x y D[u[x, y], x] == 0] 
    /. u[x, y] -> c[(x^3 - y^2)/x];
% // Simplify

(* True *)
```

In summary, the original PDE has no solution unless `z == 0`.  When `z` does vanish, `u[x, t]` is an arbitrary function of `(x^3 - y^2)/x`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed analysis!

Answer (score 1):

Maple 2017.2 outputs:
Warning: System is inconsistent .
See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/94rgfdt34pe9a9m/PDE.pdf?dl=0):
[image]

Comment: Thank-you, its a tutorial question. I guess these things happen.

Comment: This answer would be more interesting if it explained the inconsistency.

Comment: @anderstood: The execution of the above code at printlevel:=25 shows Maple uses differential algebra tools to this end. I am not a specialist in this field so I can say nothing. You may ask your questions in https://www.mapleprimes.com.

Comment: @anderstood  The characteristic equations associated with the PDE are inconsistent in that their cross derivatives are not equal.