# Solving overdetermined PDEs with DSolve or NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, boundary-conditions

I was using Mathematica 11.1 to solve a PDE system numerically, but it told me that the system is  overdetermined. So I tried a much simpler one. Here is the input.

```
s1 = NDSolve[{D[u[x, y], x, x] + D[u[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
D[u[x, y], x, y] == 0, 
u[x, 0.5] == 0.5*x, (D[u[x,y],x]/.y->0.5)==0.5,(D[u[x,y],y]/.y->0.5)==0}, 
u[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

However it didn't work and the output was

```
NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of 
(D[u[x,y],x]/.y->0.5)==0.5,(D[u[x,y],y]/.y->0.5)==0 in the first argument 
{(u^(0,2))[x,y]+(u^(2,0))[x,y]==0,(u^(1,1))[x,y]==0,u[x,0.5]==0.5 x, 
(D[u[x,y],x]/.y->0.5)==0.5,(D[u[x,y],y]/.y->0.5)==0}.
```

Another question, if I input

```
s3 = DSolve[{D[f[x, y], x, x] + D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
f[x, 0.5] == 0.5*x, (D[f[x, y], x] /. y -> 0.5) == 
0.5, (D[f[x, y], y] /. y -> 0.5) == 0}, 
f[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

then the output is the same as the input and I get nothing useful. 
However, f[x,y]=0.5x is a solution. Why can not Mathematica give me this solution?
How can I deal with these situations?

Comment: Running your code for `s1` on a fresh kernel also returns the "overdetermined" error.  Which makes sense, because the system *is* overdetermined:  it has two second-order equations for $u$ defined in the interior.

Answer (score 3):

Given the enormous number of methods available for solving differential equations symbolically, it should not be surprising that `DSolve` does not know all of them.  Indeed, searching Mathematica.StackExchange uncovers many examples, at least two of which seem relevant here, [163482](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163482/1063) and [155758](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155758/1063).  So, `DSolve` cannot solve for `s3` without assistance.  Moreover, given that it cannot do so, it naturally assumes that `s1`, which adds a PDE to the `s3` system, must be overdetermined.

The assistance required for `DSolve` to obtain the solution given in the question, `0.5 x`, is as follows.  First, verify that `0.5 x` really solves both the `s1` and `s3` systems.  For `s1` (with `u` replaced by `f` for notational consistency),

```
{D[f[x, y], x, x] + D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0, D[f[x, y], x, y] == 0, 
    f[x, 0.5] == 0.5*x, (D[f[x, y], x] /. y -> 0.5) == 0.5, 
    (D[f[x, y], y] /. y -> 0.5) == 0} /. f -> Function[{x, y}, 0.5*x]
(* {True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Similarly, the `s3` systems yields `{True, True, True, True}`.

The solution, `0.5 x`, can be derived using Mathematica as follows.  First, solve the `s3` system with no boundary conditions.

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, y], x, x] + D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}][[1, 1]]
(* f -> Function[{x, y}, C[1][I x + y] + C[2][-I x + y]] *)
```

and insert it into the `s1` system.

```
{D[f[x, y], x, x] + D[f[x, y], y, y] == 0, D[f[x, y], x, y] == 0, 
    f[x, 0.5] == 0.5*x, (D[f[x, y], x] /. y -> 0.5) == 0.5, 
    (D[f[x, y], y] /. y -> 0.5) == 0} /. %
(* {True, 
    C[1]'[0.5 + I x] + C[2]'[0.5 - I x] == 0, 
    C[1][0.5 + I x] + C[2][0.5 - I x] == 0.5 x, 
    C[1]'[0.5 + I x] - I C[2]'[0.5 - I x] == 0.5, 
    C[1]'[0.5 + I x] + C[2]'[0.5 - I x] == 0} *)
```

Note that the second and fifth terms are identical, again indicating that the `s1` and `s3` systems are, indeed, equivalent.  Next, eliminate `True` and the redundant term from the list and bring all parts of each equation to the left side for convenience to obtain.

```
eqs = Subtract @@@ (% // Union // Rest)
(* {-0.5 x + C[1][0.5 + I x] + C[2][0.5 - I x], 
    -0.5 + I C[1]'[0.5 + I x] - I C[2]'[0.5 - I x],
    C[1]'[0.5 + I x] + C[2]'[0.5 - I x]} *)
```

Now, solve systematically for `C[1]` and `C[2]`.

```
Expand[eqs[[2]] + I eqs[[3]]];
sc1 = Simplify[DSolve[(% /. (0.5` + I x) -> z) == 0, C[1][z], z, 
    GeneratedParameters -> C1] /. z -> (0.5` + I x)][[1, 1]]
(* C[1][0.5 + I x] -> (0. - 0.125 I) + (0.25 + 0. I) x + C1[1] *)

Expand[eqs[[2]] - I eqs[[3]]];
sc2 = Simplify[DSolve[(% /. (0.5` - I x) -> z) == 0, C[2][z], z, 
    GeneratedParameters -> C2] /. z -> (0.5` - I x)][[1, 1]]
(* C[2][0.5 - I x] -> (0. + 0.125 I) + (0.25 + 0. I) x + C2[1] *)

eqs[[1]] /. {sc1, sc2} /. (0.` + 0.` I) -> 0
(* C1[1] + C2[1] *)
```

Thus, the two additional constants `C1[1]` and `C2[1]` sum to zero.

```
ComplexExpand[(C[1][I x + y] + C[2][-I x + y]) /. y -> 0.5 /. {sc1, sc2}] 
    /. (0.` + 0.` I) -> 0 /. % -> 0
(* 0.5 x *)
```

Perhaps, this systematic solution of the toy problems in the question will be of help in solving conceptually similar but more difficult problems.